# integer not incrementing, list not growing... values from session c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I am building a very basic "dice cricket" simulator. I am trying to track the completed innings and overs as well as the scores using integers and lists that I am storing in the asp.net Session.

I have an "innsOver" class representing a set of 6 deliveries, with an integer for each delivery representing the outcome of the ball.

```
public class innsOver
{
public int overNumber { get; set; }
public int ball1 { get; set; }
public int ball2 { get; set; }
public int ball3 { get; set; }
public int ball4 { get; set; }
public int ball5 { get; set; }
public int ball6 { get; set; }
}
```

I also have 2 Lists based on this class, to represent 2 innings:

```
List<innsOver> inns1 = new List<innsOver>();
List<innsOver> inns2 = new List<innsOver>();
```

I have also declared integers for the number of complete inns (so I know whether I am playing inns1 or inns 2) and the number of complete overs (so i know how many overs are bowled). These are

```
int oversComplete = 0;
int innsComplete = 0;
```

The 2 integers `oversComplete` and `innsComplete` and the 2 lists `inns1` and `inns2` are declared globally.

The "over" is played by pressing a button, which calls the `playOver()` method which itself calls a `bowlDelivery()` method. When the `playOver()` method is completed it should increment the `completeOvers` integer, add the completed over to the appropriate innnings list (`inns1` or `inns2`) and return that to a gridView.

```
public void bowlOver()
{
    //other processing checks which end the over is bowled from
   //which batsman is the striker / non-striker and who is bowling.

    for (int i = 1; i <7; i++)
    {
        int x = bowlDelivery();
        int b = 0;
        if (x == 5)
        {
            //this represents a chance of a wicket that was 
            //unsuccessful so no run scored
            b = 0;
        }
        else if (x == 7)
        {
            //this means a wicket fell so i have wicket processing;
        }
        else if (x == 1 || x == 3)
        {
            b = x;
            //award 1 run & change striking batsman
        }
        else
        {
            b = x;
           //2, 4 or 6 runs awarded
        }
        //the outcome is returned to the correct ball
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                activeOver.ball1 = b;
                break;
            case 2:
                activeOver.ball2 = b;
                break;
            case 3:
                activeOver.ball3 = b;
                break;
            case 4:
                activeOver.ball4 = b;
                break;
            case 5:
                activeOver.ball5 = b;
                break;
            case 6:
                activeOver.ball6 = b;
                break;
        }

    }
    //the over result is returned to the correct inns list
    switch (innsComplete)
    {
        case 0:
            Session["inns1"] = inns1;
            Session["oversComplete"] = oversComplete;
            oversComplete = (int)Session["oversComplete"];
            activeOver.overNumber = oversComplete + 1;
            oversComplete = activeOver.overNumber;
            inns1 = (List<innsOver>)Session["inns1"];
            inns1.Add(activeOver);
            GridView3.DataSource = inns1;
            GridView3.DataBind();
            Session["inns1"] = inns1;
            Session["oversComplete"] = oversComplete;
            break;
        case 1:
            Session["inns2"] = inns2;
            Session["oversComplete"] = oversComplete;
            oversComplete = (int)Session["oversComplete"];
            activeOver.overNumber = oversComplete + 1;
            oversComplete = activeOver.overNumber;
            inns2 = (List<innsOver>)Session["inns2"];
            inns2.Add(activeOver);
            GridView3.DataSource = inns2;
            GridView3.DataBind();
            Session["inns2"] = inns2;
            Session["oversComplete"] = oversComplete;
            break;
    }
}

public int bowlDelivery()
{
   //currently the result of each ball is completely random but i will add weighting later
    int x = rnd.Next(1, 7);
    if (x == 5)
    {
        int y = rnd.Next(1, 6);
        if(y > 4)
        {
            x = 7;
        }
        else
        {
            x = 5;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

However, at the moment I only ever get a single over returned, and the overNumber is always "1". The ball values change, so it just seems to be playing the 1st over repeatedly. I'm expecting (trying to achieve) the over overNumber incrementing and additional rows being added to the innsX list displayed in the gridview.

Any suggestions of what I have wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the method **is called**?

Comment: yes, because the 1st over appears in the gridview. it just never gets past the first over.

Comment: How and where is `rnd` initialized?

Comment: also globally using `Random rnd = new Random();` I should clarify that everything is working as expected apart from the incrementing of `completeOvers` integer and the increasing rows of the `innsX` list.

Comment: Could you let us know at what event in the page cycle the method call happen? It would be great if you can share us the full code.
Some value reset is happening somewhere and it will be difficult to find it without seeing the full code.

Comment: It will be good to have checks like, 
if(Session["inns1"] == null)
    Session["inns1"] = inns1;
Only if no value exists in session, set it to session, else use the value in session which i see it in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of each `case` statement you have `Session["inns1"] = inns1;`  Where is `innsX` coming from?  Is it a new list that gets set to the Session every time?  In that case it looks like `Session["innsX"]` gets overwritten each time and thus there is only one record to display in the grid.

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I think I am doing what you say with: `activeOver.overNumber = oversComplete + 1;
            oversComplete = activeOver.overNumber;` and then at the end storing the new `oversComplete` in the Session. So my belief is I make `activeOver` 1 more than  `completeOvers`, then set `completeOvers` to `activeOver` which is the same as doing `oversComplete++` i believe?

Comment: I see that now.  Sorry.

Comment: no problem! i'm not a pro and it would in no way be unlike me to miss something like that! :)

Comment: I didn't spot your edited answer. innsX is a list declared globally. So my understanding is that it shouldn't be a "new" innsX sent to the session every time... but that code looks a bit clumsy to me. I'll play around and see what I get to. Thanks.

Comment: -so yes, I guess the problem that the `innsX` session was being overwritten. I moved the initial creation of the session values for both `innsX` lists and the `oversComplete` and `innsComplete` integers to the 'PageLoad' and so in the over all it is doing is updating them. It is now working as expected. Thanks for the pointers.